# Как посчитать общее количество значений в JSON массиве

Tags: javascript, json

Есть ассоциативный JSON массив

```
{1234: 5, 1235: 5, 1236: 7, 1237: 7}
```

Как найти общее количество его значений?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var data = {
  1234: 5,
  1235: 5,
  1236: 7,
  1237: 7
};
console.log(Object.keys(data).length);
```

```js
var data = {
  1234: 5,
  1235: 5,
  1236: 7,
  1237: 7
};

var count = 0;
for(var key in data) {
  count++;
}
console.log(count);
```