# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript

помогите решить довольно распространенную ошибку
Этой функцией я получаю из бд массив и его id

```
function init(){
var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
console.log(hash);
$.post(
 'pages/adminPage/core.php',
{
    "action":"loadSingleGoods",
    "id":hash
},
goodsOut
);
```

}

Этой функцией я хочу его распарсить и вывести на экран

```
function goodsOut(data){
//Вывод  на страницу
data=JSON.parse(data);
console.log(data);
var out="";


    out+='<div class="col-lg-2 cart pull-right">';
    out+=`<button class="later"  data-id="${data.id}">&hearts;</button>`;
    out+=`<h4 class="name">${data.name}</h4>`;
    out+=`<img src="pages/orderPage/goods/${data.img}" width="100em" height="100em">`;
    out+=`<div class="cost">${data.cost}</div>`;
    out+=`<button class="add-to-cart btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-id="data.id">купить</button>`;
    out+='</div>';


$('.goods-out').html(out);
$('.add-to-cart').on('click',addToCart);
$('.later').on('click',addToLater);
```

}

Проверял в network есть ответ сервера ф-ция loadSingleGood возвращается,но console указывает на это: data=JSON.parse(data);

Причем с другими страницами эти функции работают

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы возвращаете с сервера html, а не JSON.

```
function goodsOut(data){
  console.log(data);
  return;

  //Вывод  на страницу
  data=JSON.parse(data);
  ...
```

Comment: спасибо,помогли

Comment: @КириллЧетвертков Пожалуйста. Успехов! Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа. Здесь тоже - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/877881